# Use arrays inside struct in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a struct like below:

```
struct Document {
    address[] haveAccess;
}

mapping(uint => Document) public documents;
address[] public arr;

 constructor() {
    documentsCount++;
    documents[documentsCount] = Document(arr);
 }
```

Accessing from web3 js after compiling from truffle doesn't return the address array **haveAccess**. Even empty array is not returned.
The web3 call goes like this

```
instance.documents(0).then(document=>{
    //dosomething with document
});
```

I need the array haveAccess to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling with parenthesis instead of brackets. And you also need to add `.call`. Take a look [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

Comment: Thanks... anyway i used () only, typo in my question.. i ll edit it..
And cant use .call because its not a method, its a mapping.. it doesnt work

Comment: Did you try with `.call`? As far as I know, public variables are exposed as functions.